# Does this strange integral make sense? Does it have a reasonable solution?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Is this integral reasonable? If so, does anyone have an recommended solution methods. Most of my training is in physics, so I treat derivatives as ratios of differentials sometimes, and that is how I came across this integral, but I'm not sure if it makes sense.

$$\int e^{dx}$$

Thanks

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1068/595055) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $\int$ replace to $\prod$ , $\prod\limits_a^b f(x)^{dx}$ is the geometric product integral