# How does the definition of the differential dy imply we are talking about infinitesimal change?

Tags: differential, infinitesimals

I know differentials are seen as infinitesimal changes but I am confused because the definition of the differential doesn't seem to imply anything infinitesimal:

If $y = f(x)$ and you are in a point $x$ where the function $f$ has a derivative, and you consider a neighbouring point $x + \Delta x$, then we define the differential $dy$  as the change along the tangent line in $x$, so $dy = f'(x)\Delta x$ .

When taking the identical function $f:y= x$ and apply the definion above, we find $dx = \Delta x$ where $dx$ means the differential of the identical function.

So you can write $dy =f'(x) dx$

But defining differentials like this, they don't have to be small changes at all. They are dependent on the values of $x$ and $\Delta x$.

So far no problem, but then the differential $dx$ also appears when defining integrals
as the limit of the Riemann Sums $\Sigma f(x) \Delta x$ where $\Delta x$ goes to 0. We get the well known notation $\int f(x)dx$ where the differential symbol $dx$ magically reappears, but this time it does have the meaning of an arbritry small change of $x$.

So my confusion is, according to the definition , differentials don't have to be infinitesimal, but when they are used in the definition of integrals they suddenly do.

Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Have you read [What does $dx$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143222/what-does-dx-mean) or [Usage of $dx$ in integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/usage-of-dx-in-integrals) or [What is $dx$ in integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393/what-is-dx-in-integration)

Comment: yes sure, I know that dx in the integral notation is just symbolic. But then again, when solving integrals with substitution, we start seeing the dx (or the du) as a differential anyway. So is dx in integrals a purely symbolic thing, is it an infinitesimal change in the x-direction, or is it the differential in x according to the definition which does not have to be infinitesimally small.  It really is a mess when you start thinking about it :)

Comment: It can be, hence the numerous questions about it already. I'd recommend reading those, and if you have a specific question not addressed in any of those answers, make a new post that references those questions (to show you already researched your question) and clearly states what you are asking that is different than those questions.